# Jackson JSON Mapping JSON keys with JAVA BEAN

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I'm using Jackson JSON LIB 2.8, and i'm using         `Json.mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES,true);`

but sometimes I need to map some fields with two differents names like

POJO has attribute `builindg` and i need to map it to `buildingUid` or `BUILDING` depends on what key exist in JSON, are they any way to do this ?

Example :

```
public class Building extends Bean {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

}
```

and I have two different sources , one is my Database which return a JSON with this format :

```
{
"ID":"build",
"NAME":"name1"

 }
```

and my other source is a client :

```
{
"UID" : "build",
"name" : "name1"
}
```

As you can see my problem is to map id with both UID and ID , i manage to map the first one with :

`Json.mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES,true);`

but the other source is UID and i dont know how to map it automatically when i do something like

```
Json.encode(Building.toString());
```

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using multiple setters annotated with `@JsonSetter`

Try something like this :

```
public class Building extends Bean {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonGetter("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonSetter("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonSetter("UID")
    public void setUID(String id) {
        setId(id);
    }

    @JsonGetter("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonSetter("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonSetter("NAME")
    public void setUpperCaseName(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }        

}
```

But it's a little lousy (solution not dynamic).